# How to avoid require cycles between React components that reference each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, require

I know how to prevent Javascript require cycles in general.

However, I have the special case of two React components that reference each other. One is a Button, the other a Modal component (a Bottom Sheet to be exact). The Button, if pressed, opens the Modal. And sometimes, on the Modal, there is a Button to open the same Modal again (but with different data).

So, my Button component looks like this:

```
const Button = (props) => {
  ...
  return <TouchableOpacity ...>
    ...
    <Modal ... />
  </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

And the Modal looks like this:

```
const Modal = (props) => {
  ...
  return <BottomSheetModal ...>
    ...
    {props.somePropThatRequiresButton && <Button ... />}
  </BottomSheetModal>
}
```

If `Modal` and `Button` are not defined in the same file, this will of course lead to a Require Cycle warning.

Is there a way to prevent the Require Cycle warning without putting those components in the same file?

Comment: I cannot believe there is no way to do this. My intuition says there must be some factory pattern or some other abstraction.

Comment: You create a third component called `ModalButton` or `ButtonModal`. If you use webpack there's a good [plugin](https://github.com/aackerman/circular-dependency-plugin) to prevent cycles, and node in general offers packages like [madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge) to incorporate detection of cycles into your build process.

Comment: I don't see having a `Button` with a `Modal` inside it as a good design choice, I would rather have a third component `ButtonWithModal` or `ButtonModal` that hosts both, although this is much more related to an atomic design rather than anything else.

Comment: It's kind of hard to give a concrete solution with this little code, but your general approach should be to break this into more pieces.  Also think about what can be passed in via `props`, particularly the `children` prop.

Comment: @briosheje @morganney That third component, `ButtonModal`, would have to be referenced by the `Modal`. After all, I want the button to be rendered inside the `Modal`.

Comment: @cheesus having the modal rendering the button does not seem weird, but the opposite does. I assume you want a modal with a button and a button that actually can spawn a modal, right? If so, the design proposed above works.

Comment: @cheesus This is a very raw example of what I mean, perhaps this can be helpful: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nbluz2?file=src/App.js

Comment: @briosheje if you click the Button on the Modal, a second Modal should open. Please read my question: **The Button, if pressed, opens the modal.**

Comment: @cheesus you need to open a `modal` which have a `button` which also `open` a `modal`?
I think @briosheje right, you need to restructure your code.

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh each modal has a specific topic, and these topics are linked to other topics. So if you open the modal on topic A, and topic A is linked to topic B, we need a button on modal A which opens modal B. How should I restructure my code?

Comment: **I know how to prevent Javascript require cycles in general.** Really, how? The button referencing the modal is just wrong.

Comment: @cheesus can you create a codesandbox for me to play with?  or link to a repo?  Does clicking the B button on modal A keep both modals open, or does A close when B opens?

Comment: @LindaPaiste clicking the B button on modal A keeps both modals open. I know that seems a bit strange, but it's what the customer wants ‍♂️

Comment: @morganney why? I have this button-opens-modal situation on several screens (and on the modal itself). So instead of repeating this across several screens, I am staying DRY by creating a custom Button component (call it ModalButton if you like), and this ModalButton does always the same thing: it opens a modal if clicked. Of course there is context which is passed from the button to the modal.

Comment: @morganney if you think  "this is just wrong", please explain to me how I can avoid the reference from the Button (or ModalButton) to the modal, and at the same time not repeat the same code over and over again. Violating the DRY principle is just wrong too.

Comment: fwiw, if anyone wants the bounty, just write an answer which mentions the `React.lazy` API. This was in a deleted answer, and it seems to be what I need.

Comment: @cheesus Can you add the link to the original question as well, from where that answer got deleted

Comment: @SanujBansal it's this question. There are three deleted answers. If nobody creates an answer, the bounty points get lost in 13 hours.

Comment: @cheesus I need to write up an answer, but I have a solution using react contexts: https://codesandbox.io/s/button-modal-a-b-c-d-forked-qydihh?file=/src/ModalStackProvider.tsx

Comment: I can see the two deleted answers from Ali Beyit and Raed N.  Those were both deleted by @sideshowbarker who is a moderator so they cannot be "undeleted" :(.  There is a third deleted answer by Azhar Uddin Sheikh which was deleted by the author.